# ESTA information when living in other country than citizenship

Tags: esta

I have tried to fill out the ESTA-application, but is a bit unsure about what to answer to one of the questions.

When I go to the [ESTA-site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), I am presented with a version which is translated into my native language. For the most part this is fine, but some of the translations are somewhat off and makes them ambiguous about what they actually want to know.

First I fill out my nationality/citizenship. No problems so far.
Then I fill out my current address. Still no problems.

At one point it asks if I am resident or citizen of another country than the citizenship I already have filled out. But here the translation is rough, so I become uncertain what to answer.
I do not have another citizenship, but live in another country than my nationality/citizenship. So I selected "Yes". However, the options I can choose between to give the details about this is only about citizenship and not where I live.
Answering "No" to the question would be incorrect.
Answering "Yes" and then selecting one of the following answers would also be incorrect. However, with this option it is possible to fill out a free text field at the end (but the first answer would still be incorrect).

The question therefore is:
Should I state on the ESTA-application that I am a living in another country? Or is the question only related to people with dual citizenship?

(The question is actually not about me, but a person I am helping with the application. It was just easier to phrase like this.)

Comment: If you could mention the language you're using and quote the exact wording of the question in that language, it would make this post somewhat more useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the translation the official translation, or an automated translation using Chrome’s translation tool, for instance?

Comment: @phoog I considered that, but talked to someone else who had the same issue - in another language. Therefore, I chose to make it generic since it apparently is ambiguous in more than just my case.

Comment: @jcaron This is the official translation.

Comment: I have checked a few of the translations (french, spanish, italian) and they all have the correct language for this question. Can you specify which languages have this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The English version has the following questions for this case:

> Are you now, a citizen or national of any other country?
>   Have you ever been a citizen or national of any other country?

No mention about residency, so unless the applicant has dual-citizenship, the answer should be "No" to both. The only place where you put the place of residence is in the contact information.

I live outside of my home country, too, and have used ESTA a couple times when traveling from here without problems.